# How to send a post request to Flask based on html <select> change

Tags: python, html, flask

and thanks for taking the time to look at this.

So I am building a small web app to experiment with Flask. However I am unsure how to do this:
upon changing a value in a `<input type=number>` for instance, it sends something to the flask server (in this case the value of the input and then reloads the page with the value.
Basically what I am trying to achieve is that based on a input field, I want a certain number of input to appear via a for loop (which works fine). **The only problem is that I need to press a submit button every time** which isn't very nice.

```
    <form action="/newevent/individual" method="post" class="px-8 pt-6 mb-4 bg-white rounded">  
     <div class="mb-4 md:flex md:justify-between">  
     <div class="mb-4 md:mr-2 md:mb-0">  
     <label class="block mb-2 text-lg font-bold text-black" for="quantity">  
    Qty of individual tickets.  
     </label>  
     <label class="block mb-2 text-lg italic text-gray-500" for="quantity">  
    Please confirm before proceeding.  
     </label>  
     <div>  
     <input  
     class="w-1/2 px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-lg leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"  
     id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" min="1" max="30"  
     value="{{ quantity }}" />  
     <button type="submit" name="submit\_button" value="changequantity"  
     class="py-2 px-4 mr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700">  
    Confirm  
     </button>  
     </div>  
     </div>  
     </div>  
     </form>
```

Any ideas? (essentially, I want the form's POST submit to be done whenever the input is changed. Thank you Edit: for a bit of context, here is what it will then be used for:

```
  {% for number in range(quantity) %}
      <p>({{ number+1 }})</p>
      <input class="py-3 px-1" type="file" id="ticket{{ number }}" name="ticket {{ number }}" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf">

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the hidden attribute to "true"? like below:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit\_button" value="changequantity"
class="py-2 px-4 mr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg
border border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700" hidden="True">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But then the person has to press 'ENTER' which they might not think to do. I would need it to do a post request every time the input field is changed.